# Display channel search result was found in

Tags: ee2, search, simple-search

I'm wondering if there's any way to display the channel a search result was found in on the search results page. I have about 6 channels and I want to be able to search all of them with one search form. It gets confusing with the results though because some channels have entries with the same or a similar name. Is there anyway to include the channel the result is located in in the search result page? I haven't yet been able to really find any way of displaying the channel an entry is in yet.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup: `{channel}`. Note that all of the [Channel Entries variables](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#channel-entries-single-variables) are available within the Search Results tag.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed something so simple :P